# Why does my .catch() function not return the error name in a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, try-catch, firebase-storage

I have a function that either gets pictures from Firebase or locally saved pictures. For that I use promises. If there is no picture in Firebase to get, it should return the name of the error. This is the function:

```
function getPic(index){
    let pic = document.createElement("img");
    let errorName;
    if(tempPhotos[index] == undefined){
        storageRefPhotos.listAll().then(res=>{ 
            res.items[index].getDownloadURL().then(url=>{
                pic.src = url;
                pic.classList.add("horizontal");
            })}).catch(error => {
                console.log("The function found an "+ error.name);
                return error.name;
            });
            tempPhotos[index] = pic;
            console.log("Got it from Firebase");
            return pic;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Got it locally");
        return tempPhotos[index];
    }
}
```

The line `console.log("The function found an "+ error.name);`is executed as intended. However, in the following code, the else statement is always executed, even if the above line was executed.

```
const nextPic = getPic(currentPhoto+1);
    if(nextPic.name==="TypeError"){
        console.log("Executing the if");
        console.log("The EventListener found a "+nextPic.name);
    }
    else{
        console.log("Executing the else");
        gallery.replaceChild(nextPic, arrow_left.nextElementSibling);
        currentPhoto++;
    }
```

The idea behind this is to create a slideshow of pictures. When there are no more pictures, it should start at the beginning. The code right above this text is part of an EventListener.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I have revised my function to this:

```
function getPic(index){
    let pic = document.createElement("img");
    if(tempPhotos[index] == undefined){
        storageRefPhotos.listAll().then(res=>{ 
            res.items[index].getDownloadURL().then(url=>{
                pic.src = url;
                pic.classList.add("horizontal");
                tempPhotos[index] = pic;
                cl("Got it from Firebase");
                return pic;
            })
        }).catch(error => {
                console.log("The function found an "+ error.name);
                return error.name;
        });
    }
    else{
        cl("Got it locally");
        return tempPhotos[index];
    }
}
```

Now, it always returns undefinded. I do not understand why. Additionally I have changed nextPic.name to nextPic.

Comment: Super classic asynchronism question. `const nextPic = getPic(currentPhoto+1)` does NOT return the value you expect. For that matter it doesn't return a value at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Why `nextPic.name==="TypeError"`, when you already returning `error.name`? It should be `nextPic==="TypeError"`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are checking `nextPic.name==="TypeError"` which is `undefined` and *undefined is not equals to TypeError.*

You are already returning a `error.name`, you should only check

```
if (nextPic=="TypeError")
```